# Selecting Max Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, max

I'm looking to return the name of the individual with the most grades. I'm thinking something like `max(count(*))` but I can't quite crack it.

**Here is the dataset**

```
+ -------- Student -------- +  + -------- Grades --------- + 
+ Student_ID INT            +  + Student_ID INT            +
+ Student_Name VARCHAR(10)  +  + Assignment_ID INT         +
+                           +  + Grade INT                 +
+ ------------------------- +  + ------------------------- +
  INSERTS                        INSERTS
  (Student_ID, Student_Name)     (Student_ID, Assignment_ID, Grade)
  (1,'Alex')                     (1,10,90) (2,10,85)         
  (2, 'Brett1')                  (3,10,75) (4,10,74)
  (3,'Cora')                     (1,11,80) (2,11,81)
  (4,'David')                    (4,11,88) (6,11,86)
  (5,'Eleanor')                  (2,12,84)
  (6,'Brett2')
```

**and my attempt at a solution:**

```
SELECT s.Student_Name FROM Student s
WHERE(
  SELECT * FROM Grades g
  WHERE g.Student_ID=s.Student_ID
    and g.Assignment_ID=MAX(COUNT(g.Assignment_ID))
  )
```

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the highest assignment_ID for each student along with the associated grade ? Could you rephrase your requirement ? _(and what is assignment exactly ?)_

Comment: No, only the name of the student who has the highest assignment ID sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query might help:

```
select top 1 s.Student_ID,s.Student_Name,COUNT(g.Assignment_ID) as TotalAssignments
from Student s
inner join Grades g on s.Student_ID = g.Student_ID
group by s.Student_ID,s.Student_Name
order by COUNT(g.Assignment_ID) desc
```

Comment: Instead of GradeTotal, I'm just trying to return the name of the student who has the highest number of assignments taken. So while this correctly returns Brett1 because he had the highest SUM, is there a way to return Brett1 because his count(assignment_id) was the highest?

Comment: Yep, just use count(g.assignment_id) instead of sum. Edited my answer. @matrixfox